# How do you get audio working in a Windows 10 guest in VirtualBox (Ubuntu host)?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to get audio working in a Windows 10 machine running inside VirtualBox on Ubuntu, so I can use dictation software. Based on Googling, I've installed PulseAudio, and inside pavucontrol I have

Recording: VirtualBox: Windows (in) from [bar that moves right to the max when I talk loudly]

When I go into Windows, Sound control panel, Recording tab, I see a single 'Microphone'. The volume indicator next to it doesn't move at all.

If I use Configure/Set up Microphone from the Sound control panel/Recording tab, I get a dialog with 'Adjust the volume of Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)' and that does detect when I speak, and is in the green region... so audio is reaching some bit of Windows. But when I go back into the Recording tab, the volume indicator still doesn't move.

I'd be v. grateful for any help ... even typing out this much is rather painful without dictation software.

Comment: I have the very same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the virtual machine settings, Audio section, switch Audio Controller from ICH AC97 to Intel HD Audio. Make sure that Enable Audio Output is checked.